# Listen for click events on a LineLayer

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Various lines are added to the map representing routes using the following code:

```
private LineLayer makeLineLayer(List<GeoPoint> routePoints, String title) {

    String sourceTitle = "line-layer-" + lineCount;

    List<Position> points = new ArrayList<>(routePoints.size());
    List<Feature> routes = new ArrayList<>(routePoints.size());
    for (GeoPoint point : routePoints) {
            points.add(Position.fromCoordinates(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude()));
    }
    LineString route = LineString.fromCoordinates(points);

    Feature routeFeature = Feature.fromGeometry(route);
    routeFeature.addStringProperty("custom-line", "0");
    routes.add(routeFeature);

    GeoJsonSource linesSource = new GeoJsonSource(
                sourceTitle,
                FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(routes));
    mapboxMap.addSource(linesSource);

    LineLayer lineLayer = new LineLayer(title, sourceTitle);
    lineLayer.setProperties(
        //Sets properties...
    );

    return lineLayer;
}

LineLayer lineLayer = makeLineLayer(getRoutePoints());
mapboxMap.addLayer(lineLayer);
```

I'd like to be able to determine when one of these lines is clicked. Currently, MapBox calls `OnMapClick` and passes in a `LatLng` object. I can then query for rendered features with the `custom-line` property using the following:

```
PointF pixel = mapboxMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(point);
List<Feature> selectedKeys = mapboxMap.queryRenderedFeatures(pixel, Filter.has("custom-line"));
```

If `selectedKeys` then contains any returned `Feature` objects, I can query for their coordinates with `.getGeometry()`. Comparing those values with those from the `LatLng` object that was passed in, a rough estimate of which line was clicked can be determined. However, this is very inaccurate and troublesome when the line items are closely grouped.

How would one listen for click events on these line items?

Comment: Can you make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Answer (score 0):

According to the MapBox's Android SDK Documentation.

There is no method to click on the `LineLayer` neither in the parent class i.e. `Layer`.

If you can convert your `LineLayer` to `Polyline` you can have an inbuilt method for clicking in Android.

Refer this [link](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.2.1/index.html) to get clarity on it.

This is the method details of it.
`onPolylineClick
void onPolylineClick(@NonNull Polyline polyline)`

**

> Called when the user clicks on a polyline.

**

**Parameters:**

`polyline` - The polyline the user clicked on.